# tunnel for service target port empty kubernetes and can't access pod from local browser

Tags: kubernetes

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: identityold-deployment
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: identityold
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: identityold
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: identityold
        image: <image name from docker hub>
        ports:
        - containerPort: 8081
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  labels:
    app: identityold
  name: identityold-svc
  namespace: default
spec:
  type: NodePort  # use LoadBalancer as type here
  ports:
    - port: 80
      targetPort: 8081
      nodePort: 30036
  selector:
    app: identityold
```

The above code is my deployment YAML file.

[image]

and cant access from the browser the service

Comment: Can you add more details about you minikube configuration? Which guide did you follow? Are you using virtual machine for you minikube cluster?

Answer (score 0):

Exposing a service in minikube cluster is little bit different than in normal kubernetes cluster.

Please follow this [guide](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tutorials/hello-minikube/#create-a-service) from kubernetes documentation and use `minikube service` command in order to expose it properly.